# Printing size of the largest file and the average file size

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hey so I've the most convenient way to get the largest file size to print in a format of

(Values in this output only serve as an example

> Largest file size: 2015
>   Size of an average file: 1132

so to get the largest file size, i'd probably use the command

`find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | head -n 1`

This will print a lengthy list of multiple attributes and print the largest of them (based on their file size)

Issue is, I can't really find a way to get only the actual file size and nothing else

In similar fashion, what I want is to get the average file size.

So I need to find a way, to sum the file size of all the files and then divide it through number of files

To get the number it is quite easy, just a simple (find . -type f | wc -l)
bigger issue is about the summary.

Ideally I'd like the solutions to be in a simple format of

eg. `echo "Largest file size: $(find . -type f | command | command)"`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

largest file

```
find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | sort -nr | head -1 | cut -f1
```

average file size

```
find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | awk '{sum+=$1; c++} END{print sum/c}'
```

of course when you have `awk` there is no need to do it twice

```
$ find . -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n" | 
  awk 'max<$1{max=$1}
             {sum+=$1; c++}
          END{print "largest: "max; print "average: " sum/c}'

largest: 74
average: 19
```

of course if you're not going to use the file name you can change to `printf "%s"`

Comment: The command `du -s` gives a summary of disk usage. Divide by the number of files and that's the average.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *cut* command to print just part of one line separated by some delimeter

For the biggest filesize, you can use:

```
 echo "Largest file size: $(find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | head -n 1 | cut -d' ' -f2)"
```

For the average size, multiple options are viable. You can use awk:

```
 echo "Average file size: $(find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7  | cut -d' ' -f2 | awk '{ total += $1; count++ } END { print total /count}')"
```

Comment: Doesn't work, prints just an empty command line. The cut must be set up incorrectly. Will try to take a bit more indepth look into it. My assumption would be, because the files don't have even amount spaces between them after the find writeup

Comment: I just edited the commands to be one line, probably formatting issue from my side, as there was a newline in the middle of commands. Works now?

Comment: Found a solution to it, well there are multiple to it. I personally used sed to remove all [:blank:] characters and insert a single space (blank) inbetween.

Link to solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36271115/replacing-unknown-amount-of-blank-spaces-for-x-amount/36271962#36271962