# Replacing unknown amount of blank spaces for X amount

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Hey so I'm writing a linux script and I came to an interesting finding.

I've got a command that will sort the files inside a directory by it's size and prints the largest one. Command is as follows

`find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | head -n 1`

This will print something amongst the likes of

`895918591     8 -r-w-x   1 user01     xdf           1931     28  march 23:21 ./myscript.sh`

So I want to to get the largest file size alone and print it. To separate it I used `cut -d' ' -f2` issue is, this leaves only empty output. That is because the amount of spaces is inconsistent.

So I tried doing something like this

`find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | head -n 1 | tr -d [:blank:] | cut -d' ' -f2`

Issue is, this removes all the blank spaces now I can't separate them by common separator. So I'm asking, is there a way to replace literally all the blank spaces and then replace them with a single blank space?

If not, at least any other way to get to that number of bytes?

Comment: Instead of `tr`, use `sed 's/\s\+/ /g'` to replace any occurence of multiple whitespaces with one space. Optionally, `sed 's/\s\+/:/g'` to replace it with colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sed and Awk are great tools for this kind of thing. Sed is a regex-based language that modifies the contents of each line the Sed program receives, and Awk is also a line-oriented tool that automatically splits its input into fields.

To turn sequences of blanks into one blank (substitute all matches of `/\s+/` with ) in Sed:

```
$ find ... | sed 's/\s+/ /g'
```

To just print the first "word" (sequence of nonspaces) of each line in Awk:

```
$ find ... | awk '{print $1}'
```

http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sedawk.html can get you started with these languages.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `cut` you can use `awk`:

```
find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | head -n 1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

However you can even avoid `head` as well using `awk`:

```
find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | awk '{print $2; exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

The tool to convert multiple spaces to just one is called `tr -s`:

- [`tr`](http://ss64.com/bash/tr.html) translates
- `s` squeezes

Sample:

```
$ cat a
hello    this is     a sample   text   with     multiple   spaces
$ tr -s " " < a
hello this is a sample text with multiple spaces
```

If you then want to convert every space into X, just pipe to `sed 's/ /    /g'`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking the issue at hand:

```
find -type f -printf "%s\n"|sort -n|tail -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using cut, you can try using the printf command that gives you control over your display

```
find . -type f -ls | sort -r -n -k7 | head -n 1 -printf %s
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

Parsing `ls` in any form ( like `find`'s `-ls` option ) is the bad approach.

Do not use `ls` output for anything. `ls` is a tool for interactively looking at directory metadata. Any attempts at parsing `ls` output with code are broken.

I strongly suggest you to read further about this subject. Read [Parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

---

Instead, use the following function:

```
# Usage: largest [dir]
largest() {
    local f size largest

    while read -rd '' f; do
        size=$(wc -c < "$f")
        if (( size > largest[0] )); then
            largest=("$size" "$f")
        fi
    done < <(find "${1-.}" -type f -print0)

    printf '%s is the largest file in %s\n' "${largest[1]}" "${1-.}"
}
```

Comment: using `wc -c` seems a rather expensive way of finding a files size. What about `stat`? Good luck to all.